# Send parameters through the URL after form submission

Tags: html, jquery, woocommerce

I have a simple product selection form where user gets to select how many products to buy. Based on his selection, I would need to append the URL with his selection. If he selects Product1 and Product2 the submit button should add those two products to the cart with the following parameters `https://example.com?add-to-cart=10,20`

Here is example of my form

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" id="10" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <label for="vehicle1"> Product 1</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="20" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
  <label for="vehicle2"> Product 2</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="30" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
  <label for="vehicle3"> Product 3</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I achieve this?

Found something similar [here](https://help.instapage.com/hc/en-us/articles/214578787-Send-parameters-through-the-URL-after-form-submission) but don't know how to modify it per my example.

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect to example.com?add-to-cart=10,20

```
<script>
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
          e.preventDefault(); 
        
          let params = ''    
          const redirect_url = 'axample.com?add-to-cart'            
          let count = $('input[name^="vehicle"]:checked').length
          
          $('input[name^="vehicle"]:checked').each(function(index) {
                
                    params += $(this).attr('id')
                    
                    if(index !== count - 1) {
                        params += ','
                    } 
                
          });

        // Amend redirect url in form by adding fields from form
        window.location.href = redirect_url + '=' + params         
    });
<script>
```